# Is it possible to access localstorage from Angular proxy.config.js file?

Tags: angular, local-storage, http-proxy

I am trying to use proxy to update the base url and also append the token from the local storage. I am able to update the URL but when I try to access the token it gives me error
`ReferenceError: window is not defined`. Is it possible to access local storage from proxy. I tried `localstorage.getItem('token')` and also `windows.localstorage.getItem('token')`.

My `proxy.conf.js` file looks like this

```js
const PROXY_CONF = [
    {
        context: ['/testData/*'],
        target: 'https://test.com/',
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        bypass: function (req, res, proxyOptions) {
            req.headers['authorization'] = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.localStorage.getItem(`token`) : '';
        },
    }
];
module.exports = PROXY_CONF;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy.config.js is a configuration used by webpack internally. It doesn't have any knowledge about the browser. This server is **ONLY** used for development purposes and you won't deploy/use this guy in an actual prod environment.

If you want to add a bearer token (or any other kind of tokens) to your requests you'll have to create an [**interceptor**](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor). Here's a [link](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-httpclient-http-interceptor/) to a tutorial

Comment: I want to add token to the request happening from the web component and also the custom element that we have created internally. I tried interceptor but it doesnt work with the custom element. Do you know how to intercept the requests inside library and custom element?